# A-Frame .png transparency

Tags: aframe

In Firefox .png files take on the background color of whatever they are in front of. The transparent area is white if the background is white when moving the camera in space. Also, if two pngs are directly in front of each other I get a flickering effect. I'm on windows using the latest version of Firefox. Should I be using .gif files instead of .png?

Comment: Can you provide sample code (with JSFiddle, CodePen, or Glitch)? I'm thinking you might need to set `material.alphaTest` to `0.5`.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. It's layer ordering I think. I will upload this and send a link. I also have the same issue with a logo "Cable Hall of Fame" in another piece I'm working on where the background is black and as the camera moves up to the logo you can't see anything behind it except for the basic shapes but the images, other image files, are hidden. I will setup a Glitch account. But, a good example is here: http://cablecenter.org/vr/chof2017/  you can see the png file appears to be a jpg with a black background. It has taken on the color from the scene.

Comment: Also, see how the snow particles are behind the png of the building and yet ordering has the entity in front of the png? http://cablecenter.org/vr/snow-test/

Answer (score 2):

The master branch of A-Frame exposes `material.alphaTest` property which you can set to 0.5 to resolve this transparency issue.

If you want to stay on 0.5.0, a workaround is:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('alpha-test', {
  dependencies: ['material'],

  init: function () {
    var material = this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material;
    material.alphaTest = 0.5;
    material.needsUpdate = true;
  }
});
```

Then:

```
<a-image id="yourCOFHOFimage" alpha-test></a-image>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! I will start using the master version until 6.0 comes out. To expose the alpha in master do I do this? <a-image id="yourCOFHOFimage" alpha-test="0.5"></a-image>? Also, is this the same problem I'm having with the building .png and particles? The snow particles stay behind the building even though the particles are in front in 3D. http://cablecenter.org/vr/snow-test/

Comment: Solved my own issue with the a-frame particle component. It renders in HTML order from top to bottom. So, the last line of the scene needs to have the loader entity:
<a-entity position="0 2.25 0" particle-system="preset: snow; particleCount: 5000" alpha-test></a-entity>
</scene>

Comment: Thanks, alphaTest on the a-image fixed this perfectly for me, needsUpdate wasn't required

Answer (score 2):

```
<a-entity class="xyz" material="transparent: true"></a-entity>
```

just make transparent: true in material.

Comment: This worked better than alpha-test for me. I was using `a-image` png on top of `a-video`. Setting alpha-test will fix some transparency issue, but the image will become jaggy. Transparent works as expected.